# Combine rows ignoring null values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to combine the rows which has null values and keep only the unique combination.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Query:** I tried to take the maximum per group but since it considers null value it is not combining. Can you please suggest how to combine values.

```
SELECT SALES_ORG 
              ,MAX(MATERIAL) OVER (PARTITION BY  SALES_ORG,MATERIAL ORDER BY MATERIAL) as MATERIAL
              ,MAX(MGROUP) OVER (PARTITION BY SALES_ORG,MATERIAL,MGROUP ORDER BY MGROUP  ) as MGROUP  
              ,MAX(SERVICE) OVER (PARTITION BY SALES_ORG,MATERIAL,MGROUP,SERVICE ORDER BY SERVICE  ) as SERVICE 
              
    FROM SALES
```

Comment: Your output excludes some null values and includes others. So please explain the logic which permits `XS13/null/10/ZSERV2` and `XS13/M2/null/null` whilst filtering out `XS13/null/10/XSERV1` and `XS13/null/10/null`.  There may be many ways to achieve your desired output, but devising a **correct** way depends on understanding the business rules you're trying to implement. If the logic depends on **the order** in which records are read please include the sorting logic to be applied.

Comment: Also, do you have any expectation regarding performance? Will this be running over a large amount of data? Any other restrictions (e.g. requirement for pure SQL only)?

Comment: @APC - Data is not very high and not restricted to SQL , I can write a function also. No performance problem. MGROUP/MATERIAL/SERVICE is the order. I have to start from the full combination , if it is present then ignore all the other, Then traverse MATERIAL/SERVICE. Finally MGROUP

Comment: What happens to XS14?

Comment: Is there a unique identifier column too?

Comment: @MatBailie - No unique identifier thats the problem for me . XS14 is a separate line

Comment: XS14 is in your input but not your output.

Comment: Oh I am sorry , I missed that line

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to do any aggregation / combining. Instead, all rows in the output came from the input, but some input rows are filtered out. Specifically, row 1 is excluded and row 3 is excluded, no aggregation at all.  Please could you update your question to either confirm you only need to filter out rows, or to show an example that can only be solved by combining rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your output by aggregating by the first 3 columns and taking the maximum of the `service` column:

```sql
SELECT sales_org,
       material,
       mgroup,
       MAX(service) AS service
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       sales_org,
       material,
       mgroup;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (sales_org, material, mgroup, service) AS
SELECT 'XS13', NULL, 10,   'ZSERV1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XS13', 'M1', 10,   'ZSERV1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XS13', NULL, 10,   NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XS13', NULL, 10,   'ZSERV2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XS13', NULL, 11,   'ZSERV2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XS13', 'M2', 12,   'ZSERV2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XS14', 'M2', NULL, NULL     FROM DUAL;
```

Gives the output:

> | SALES_ORG | MATERIAL | MGROUP | SERVICE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | XS13 | *null* | 10 | ZSERV2 |
> | XS13 | M1 | 10 | ZSERV1 |
> | XS13 | *null* | 11 | ZSERV2 |
> | XS13 | M2 | 12 | ZSERV2 |
> | XS14 | M2 | *null* | *null* |

---

#### Update:

From comments:

> I have to first check MGROUP/SERVICE/MATERIAL if this combination is present then ignore all the other with the same value/combination. If only SERVICE/MATERIAL is present Then ignore all the otehr below combination.

You can use a hierarchical query to connect each row to more specific rows and then find the leaf rows:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       sales_org,
       material,
       mgroup,
       service
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
      (PRIOR sales_org = sales_org OR PRIOR sales_org IS NULL)
  AND (PRIOR material  = material  OR PRIOR material  IS NULL)
  AND (PRIOR mgroup    = mgroup    OR PRIOR mgroup    IS NULL)
  AND (PRIOR service   = service   OR PRIOR service   IS NULL);
```

Which outputs the same as above.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=232bc80f86f367ef94c6154f822713c6)*

Comment: Thank you but its not so straight forward , may be i did not explain correectly. I have to first check MGROUP/SERVICE/MATERIAL if this combination is present then ignore all the other with the same value/combination. If only SERVICE/MATERIAL is present Then ignore all the otehr below combination.

Comment: @Satheesh Updated with a hierarchical solution. Also assuming that you want to include `sales_org` in the combination; if you do not then you should not get the `XS14` row and there is a more specific row `XS13/M2/12/ZSERV2`.