# Merge rows which has same pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to combine rows into 1 which has same pattern. I am not sure how to acheive it.

I tried to merge with MAX but since its a string, not sure if there is way to combine.

```
SELECT ID,MAX(GRP1),MAX(GRP2),MAX(GRP3),MAX(GRP)                                                       
FROM GROUP_MAPPING 
GROUP BY ID
```

From table:

[image]

To Table

[image]

Comment: This sounds quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71051217/266304) from earlier today. Anyway... please post formatted text, not images; edit the question to include your sample data expected results as text, and the output of your current query, and if it's wrong explain why - the logic to get to your expected result isn't necessarily obvious, so explaining how you want to combine/merge the data would be useful.

Comment: As was mentioned above and in the previous question, please provide the rule to "group" rows together. Because there are many ways to fit source data to your current expected output, but without specification they all worth noting. The simplest is: `where grp1 is not null and grp2 is not null`

Comment: Why does the first row of data have three `A`s? The `grp` appears to be formed from  `grp1 || grp2 || grp3` with the exception of that one row where there is an extra character.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same principle as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71052323/1509264):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       id,
       grp1,
       grp2,
       grp3,
       grp
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR id = id
AND    grp LIKE '%' || PRIOR grp1 || '%' || PRIOR grp2 || '%' || PRIOR grp3 || '%';
```

or

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       id,
       grp1,
       grp2,
       grp3,
       grp
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR id = id
AND    (PRIOR grp1 = grp1 OR PRIOR grp1 IS NULL)
AND    (PRIOR grp2 = grp2 OR PRIOR grp2 IS NULL)
AND    (PRIOR grp3 = grp3 OR PRIOR grp3 IS NULL)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, grp1, grp2, grp3, grp) AS
SELECT 'DEPT1', 10,   'AA', 'S1', '10AAAS1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEPT1', NULL, 'AA', 'S1', 'AAS1'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEPT1', 10,   NULL, NULL, '10'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEPT1', 10,   'BB', NULL, '10BB'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEPT1', NULL, 'BB', NULL, 'BB'      FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | ID | GRP1 | GRP2 | GRP3 | GRP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | DEPT1 | 10 | AA | S1 | 10AAAS1 |
> | DEPT1 | 10 | BB | *null* | 10BB |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e32c3490e9b37b43a6ae097b05a78150)*